# How to copy and transform all messages from one kafka topic (in avro format) to another topic (in json format)

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

My team is using Kafka Confluent (enterprise version) and we are very new to kafka.
We have 2 topic A and B.

Topic A will receive all json messages and formatted by Avro Schema (using URL to schema registry).

By some reasons, The development tool we are using does not support receiving messages from topic A in avro format. We create Topic B and want to use KsqlDB to copy all messages from topic A to topic B and also transform all messages from avro format to normal json format so that we can develop a component that can pick up json messages from topic B.

Could you please show me code to create ksql stream to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Register the inbound Avro data stream

```sql
CREATE STREAM MY_AVRO_SOURCE
  WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='my_source_topic', FORMAT='AVRO');
```

Tell ksqlDB to read all messages from the beginning of the topic

```sql
SET 'auto.offset.reset' = 'earliest';
```

Write all the messages to a new stream in JSON

```sql
CREATE STREAM MY_JSON_TARGET 
  WITH (FORMAT='JSON') 
  AS SELECT * FROM MY_AVRO_SOURCE;
```

By default this will populate a target topic called `MY_JSON_TARGET`; you can specify `KAFKA_TOPIC` in the `WITH` clause if you want to use a different target topic name.

If only the value (not key) in the source is Avro then use `VALUE_FORMAT` instead of `FORMAT` in the `WHERE` clause.

Ref: https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/reference/serialization/

Comment: Thanks. I did that. I have 2 topics set up. But while I can see messages coming to topic "my_source_topic", I dont see any message in topic STREAM MY_JSON_TARGET.  We have an avro schema in topic "my_source_topic". Do we need to have any JSON schema for topic "STREAM MY_JSON_TARGET" ?

Comment: What do you get if you `PRINT 'my_source_topic' FROM BEGINNING LIMIT 5` ?

Comment: You don't need to define the target JSON schema; it's inherited from the source stream

Comment: running query: PRINT 'my_source_topic' FROM BEGINNING LIMIT 5. I can see records in that topic.

Comment: It is working now after working with Kafka Admin team. The issue is the access right that my account need to have. Thanks Robin.

Comment: This doesn't seem to copy the key from the source topic to the new topic.